# Vee-validade vue3 setErrors can't define filed

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vee-validate

I am using Vue 3 and vee-validate and yup schema to validate a form before sending the post request and it's working ok, but my problem is when the response comes from the server, for example, a duplicated email, I am struggling to validate the errors.
If i do this:

```
form.value.setErrors({
     email: 'my error message'
 });
```

it works ok!

but i want to loop in my array of errors to see the fields(param) and the error messages(msg)
but i can’t define the param as i do her:

```
for (const error of errors.response.data.errors) {
  let param = error.param;
  let msg = error.msg;
  form.value.setErrors({
     param: msg
  });
}
```

What i expect is loop in my “errors.response.data.errors” and setErrors () with-param and msg variables

Answer (score 0):

[Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) feature was introduced in ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) that allows you to dynamically compute the names of the object properties in JavaScript object literal notation.

i had to use [param]:msg